# Passing the Model values back to Controller Method after submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I have a view that asks a user to upload Excel file, my controller reads the excel file and returns the results as a Model. The Model contains List of Strings called AssingednUmbers `public List<String> AssignedNumbers { get; set; }`

The values are displayed on a View Page. Everything works fine upto this step. Now I have a Method called DownloadFile

```
[HttpPost]
        public FileResult DownloadFile(OnvoyModel model)
```

It has a Model entry and returns csv file . The conversion and everything is working fine. but The Model that I am passing to DownloadFile is always Empty. after uploading Excel file and returning the results(Numbers) on the page when they user click on the Download Button, the controller calles the DownloadFile Method but the Model is Null. How can I pass the Model with the List inside of it from before back to my Controller

```
 // Looping through my List that comes from the Model
<table>
    @foreach (var Number in Model.AssignedNumbers) { 
        <li>
            @Number


        </li>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AssignedNumbers);
    }
</table>

<td>
///Submitting to download the new list and calling the Method
   @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "PhoneBookProcessing", FormMethod.Post))
   {
      @Html.Action("DownloadFile", new { model = Model.AssignedNumbers })
   }
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Download This File</button>
    </div>
   }
```

Model

```
public class OnvoyModel
    {
        public List<String> AssignedNumbers { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out .
Pass it as a hidden field
View
    for (int item = 0; item < subjectsCount; item++)
                {
                    **@Model.AssignedNumbers[item].ToString()**
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AssignedNumbers[item])
                }
            }